# Program in C not working

Tags: c, arrays

Ok, so I'm writing a program to make a 10 x 10 array filled with random numbers between 0 & 9, and (with each step organized into a function):

(a) sum the first row and print it out
(b)print out average of main diagonal (top to bottom, left to right)
(c)print out how many 0's are in the first column
(d)make more 10 x 10 arrays with random numbers between 0 & 9 and if all the values in the main
    diagonal (top to bottom, left to right) are 7 or greater, print out the array, and the 
    amount of tries it took. If it can't do it in 1,000,000 attempts, print that it could not
    be done.
(e)make a 1D dynamically allocated array containing 10 numbers between -10 & +10, multiply by
    the first array made and display the resulting vector

Can't figure out what's not making it work, getting the wrong values for all the steps when they're printed out :'( and some errors

```
void simple_array(int ten_by_ten[10][10])
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)    
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; ++j)
        {
            ten_by_ten[i][j] =  rand() % 10;
            printf("%d ", ten_by_ten[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void sum_first_row(int y[10][10])
{
    int i = 0, j, sum_row = 0;
    for (j=0; j<10; ++j)
    { 
        sum_row += y[i][j];
    }
    printf("\nThe sum of the first row is: %d\n", sum_row);
}

void average_main_diagonal(int z[10][10])
{
    int i, j = 0, average_diagonal = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
    { 
        ++j;
        average_diagonal += z[i][j]; 
    }
    printf("\nThe average of the diagonal is: %lf\n", (average_diagonal / 10.0));
}

void zeros(int a[10][10])
{
    int i, j = 0, zeroz = 0;
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
    { 
        if (a[i][j] == 0)
            ++zeroz;
    }
    printf("\nThere are %d zero's in the first column\n", zeroz);
}

void multiple_arrays()
{
    int sum_diagonal = 0,array[10][10], i, j, k, l, c;
    while ((sum_diagonal < 70) && (c <= 1000000))
    {
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        l = 0;
        i = 0;
        for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            for (j=0; j<10; ++j)
            {
                array[i][j] =  rand() % 10;
            }
        }
        for (k=0; k<10; ++k)
        { 
            ++l;
            sum_diagonal += array[k][l]; 
        }
        ++c;
    }
    if (c = 1000000)
        printf("\nCould not get a diagonal with numbers >= 7\n");
    else
    {
        j = 0;
        i = 0;
        for (i=0; i<10; ++i);   
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (j=0; j<10; ++j)
                printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("It took %d many tries to get a diagonal with all numbers >= 7", c);
    }

}

void array_multiplication(int b)
{   
    int **arrays, i, j, k, l, m, prod[10];
    arrays = (int **) calloc (10, sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
        arrays[i] = (int *) calloc (1, sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1)
    {   
        arrays[i] =  (rand() % 21) -10;     
    }

    for (k=0; k<10; ++k)
    {
        prod[k] = 0;
        for (l=0; l<10; ++l)
            prod[k] = prod[k] + b[k][l] * arrays[l];
    }
    printf ("The product is: <");
    for (m=0; m<10; ++m)
        printf ("%d, ", prod[m]);
    printf (">\n");
}

int main()
{
    int x[10][10];

    simple_array(x);
    sum_first_row(x)
    average_main_diagonal(x);
    zeros(x);
    multiple_arrays();
    array_multiplication(x);


    return (0);
}
```

Getting the following errors:

When I comment out the "array multiplication" function (because it's getting the following errors: (a) assignment makes pointer from integer without cast "arrays[i] = (rand() % 21) -10;" (b) value is neither array nor pointer "prod[k] = prod[k] + b[k][l] * arrays[l];" (c) passing arg1 of "array_multiplication" makes integer from pointer without cast "array_multiplication(x);"

and it prints out an incorrect average of the diagonal

Help is Extremely appreciated!!!
Thanks,
--Rob

Comment: Why don't you wait on the [previous SAME question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752622/c-program-not-working-properly) you just posted 40 mins ago instead of creating another one? If you've to, edit and reword that one and not create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`arrays[i] =  (rand() % 21) -10;` : `arrays[i]` is a pointer. You can't assign an integer to a pointer.  Actually you just assigned some allocated memory to `arrays[i]` on the previous line, so even if this worked you would leak that memory.

Maybe you meant to have two nested loops, if you want to put a value in every row and every column?
Also you never free the memory you `calloc`'d. And don't cast the value returned by calloc either.

The other errors, you meant to declare your function as

```
void array_multiplication(int b[10][10])
```

instead of `(int b)`. It is complaining that you are doing array operations on an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out

Comment: How can I fix the "arrays[i] =  (rand() % 21) -10;" & the calloc problem? I'm basically supposed to dynamically allocate a 1D array then multiply by the first array. But I'm not sure how to dynamically allocate the memory properly.

thanks :)

Comment: You allocated the memory OK. You need to use two indices to access `int`s since it is a 2-D array though, for example `arrays[i][j] = rand()...`

Comment: A fe wlines after that you have the same issue with `arrays[l]`  - you need to use two indices again to get an `int`.  If you're not actually sure how matrix multiplication works, then find out how to do it by hand first, before you try to program it

Answer (score 0):

Your code that looks at the diagonals is incorrect (which you knew).  You are incrementing "j" before using it...and so "i" is 0 and "j" is 1...which is not the diagonal.  You either need to do your "++j" AFTER using it to look up the value....but would be better suited to just use z[i][i] (use "i" for BOTH indices).

This problem happens in both average_main_diagonal and multiple_arrays.